# let wordpress create new page with users content

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering what would be the best way to let wordpress create idivual pages :

the project is as followed :

1. User makes account
2. Wordpress creates account and an account page, this page however is completely different from the wordpress theme. (easy i know, You could compare it with a profile page for the user but with much more content to fill in)
3. after user has filled in additional content wordpress should create the new page with the specific page design. Users should be able to edit content afterwards. Paying users should be able to export the generated page. Pages should be visible for public and be like domain.com/user

I am not sure how the best approach would be for this project as i am not that familiar with wordpress. My first thought is trough a childtheme, but im not sure if this would work.

Any advice?

Kind Regards

Comment: Better fit for [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can you please elaborate or rephrase your question. Couldn't make much semse out of it.

Comment: the bottleneck is that Wordpress should make the user profiles public and accessible trough a unique url.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org), this is exactly what it is designed for.